# Расчет "цветовой карты" в C#

Tags: c#, цвета

Нужно чтобы числа от 0 до 255 соответствовали такой вот color map [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и в результате получались три числа RGB, например (0,0,255)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вам поможет вот эта иллюстрация с Википедии ([ссылка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSV_(%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C)))

[image: Иллюстрация, демонстрирующая отношение между RGB и HSV]

Ваш пример начинается с 240° и идет налево до 0°.

Вам нужно разделить всю ширину на 4 области.

- 1 четверть: Синий 100%, Зеленый растет от 0% до 100%
- 2 четверть: Зеленый 100%, Синий уменьшается со 100% до 0%
- 3 четверть: Зеленый 100%, Красный растет от 0% до 100%
- 4 четверть: Красный 100%, Зеленый уменьшается со 100% до 0%

Думаю с арифметикой приведения вы справитесь

Answer (score 5):

Немного поработал над вашей картинкой.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если рассмотреть, то понятно что

- синий цвет идет от 0 до 127 с интенсивностью от 255 до 0.
- зеленый цвет идет от 0 до 127 с интенсивностью от 0 до 255 и от 128 до 255 с интенсивностью от 255 до 0
- красный цвет от 128 до 255 с интенсивностью от 0 до 255
  Основываясь на это пишем код:

> ```
> struct Color {
>   public Color(int r, int g, int b) { R = r; G = g; B = b;}
>   int R,G,B;
> }
>
> Color getColor(int color)
> {
>   int red = (color >= 128) ? (color - 128)*2 : 0;
>   int green = (color < 128) ? color*2 : 255 - (color - 128)*2; 
>   int blue = (color < 128) ? 255 - 2*color : 0;
>   return new Color(red,green,blue);
> }
> ```

Передает в функцию число от 0 до 255, получаем цвет в RGB.

P.S. Возможно, плохо обработал граничные значения (0, 127 или 128 и 255).